# How to add styles to nb-menu items

Tags: html, css, angular, ngx-admin

I am using ngx- admin template. There i use corporate theme. I use a menu in my project.

```
<div class="menuA" >
         <nb-menu [items]="items" style="background-color: white "></nb-menu>        
</div>
```

I have declared menu items in .ts file. But I cannot apply customised color to my menu items. If I apply with,

```
 ::ng-deep.nb-theme-corporate nb-menu .menu-item > .menu-items > .menu-item {
   border: none;
   background: #f4f4f7;
   color: #27679a;
   padding: 0 1.25rem;
 }
```

It applies for the whole file. How can I apply styles only to 'menuA' ?

Comment: `::ng-deep .menuA nb-menu ...other selectors here....`

Comment: Thanx. It is correct.